# Unable to install Spotify on Ubuntu 15.04. Where do I find package spotify-client?

Tags: package-management, cpu, spotify

I have followed the basic instructions that Spotify.com provides, running the commands. But after running them all I get a message saying "Unable to locate package spotify-client". Now, I read somewhere here that if my CPU does not support 64-bit then it's really hard getting it. What can I do?'

Edit: Here is the instructions https://www.spotify.com/no/download/linux/ . 
Also, how do I know what my CPU supports?

Comment: Can you [edit] into your question a link to the instructions you provided? __Please__ _don't comment it in_.

Comment: where these the instructions? https://www.spotify.com/us/download/linux/

Comment: Yes, those are the instructions I was referring to.